# Georeference Image Grid with Reference Points

Tags: algorithm, geolocation, geo

I have a tiled image of in total `n` times `m` pixel representing a true to scale area on earth. I map three points of this plan to their real world latitude and longitude values.

Now based on gps input of the users current latitude/longitude I would like to calculate and visualise the users position on the plan.

I tried to work with triangulation, but I kind of got stuck by calculating the angles between lat/long points if this is the right path at all.

Example:

The plan:

```clj
{:width 4096, :height 4096}
```

Known Points:

```clj
[{:x 1659, :y 2910, :lat 48.20483, :long 16.37957}
 {:x 1535, :y 2850, :lat 48.20498, :long 16.37922}
 {:x 1771, :y 2517, :lat 48.20554, :long 16.37982}]
```

The latitude/longitude I'd like to localise:

```clj
{:lat 48.20564, :long 16.37974}
```

I'm basically searching for a text book algorithm on this issue but my search was not successful until now. Any hints, books or sites you could reference?